# Android Video Capture Sample App

Tags: android, video-capture

Is there a stand-alone sample code for video capturing in Android ?

Answer (score 23):

Here is what I provide to my students: [Camcorder Source](http://itp.nyu.edu/~sve204/mobilemedia_spring10/Camcorder.zip)

Comment: Change `Camcorder -> onKeyDown :: KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER` to `KEYCODE_SEARCH` if your phone doesn't have a physical keyboard. That way hitting search will turn on and off the recording. Also note that the Camcorder Activity calls `finish()` when you stop recording, which closes the app.

Comment: This is awesome but I'm having a hard time get the app to show a preview before it starts recording.

Comment: hello @vanevery is there any way to record device screen video as wel as audio..please let me know if it is Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why I didn't think of this sooner. If you're just looking to capture a video so you can take that video and upload it to a server (or do something similar) you can use the native camera app extremely easily using intents.

Launch the intent, capture the video, then return to your activity, and access the video via onActivityResult.

```
// Setup a result flag for your video capture
int ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO = 100;

// Launch an intent to capture video from MediaStore
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO);

// Obtain the file path to the video in onActivityResult
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

    if (requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_VIDEO) {

        Uri videoUri = data.getData();
        String filePath = getPath(videoUri);
        Log.d("LOGCAT", "Video path is: " + filePath);
    }
}
```

More at http://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Answer (score 2):

I found a good solution from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidVideoComponent.aspx)

Comment: hello @krishna is there any way to record device screen video as wel as audio..please let me know if it is Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a stand-alone code sample, but in the [Android camera documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html), in the Class overview, there is a very nice step by step procedure that shows you how to record video.

I think is nearly as well as a sample code.